# what is Technical Architecture or 3 tier architecture

Tags: architecture

I am new to documentation part of project

normaly people follow 3 tier architecture

1) Presentation layer
2) middle layer or service layer
3) database layer

presentation means UI and Database is DB

service layer i am confused ... i assume if i am not wrong its java/dotnet/php

i came up with a statement as 'service layer abstracts business logic and data access' what is business logic?

my new peoject is a combination of HTML, CSS, JS, AngularJS, JSP, Hibernate, DB2

where does AngularJS, JSP, Hibernate resides and why?

Answer (score 0):

The three layers are and do the following:

1. *client / presentation layer*

   does only display data to the user and recive user input and send input data to the second layer on the server.
2. *service / logic layer*

   contains the application logic and processes the application data using the user input and data from the database.
3. *database layer*

   conststs usually of a database management system and is only used to store the data.

In the context of a web service:

the client layer is the html page with javascript for some client side functionality like animations. Nothing is processed here.
example: form and a login button

the application layer might be the php part of the website that takes the user requests and accesses the database to create the data that shall be displayed by the client layer.
example: when the user presses the button this layer asks the database if the data in the form exists and checks if it is valid and sends the appropriate response to the client layer.

the database layer most commonly is a MySQL server that manages the data of the service.
example: user account data